# How to get pwd from find into grep?

Tags: bash, shell

For example:

There is dir `A` where is included dir's `asdf.0-100`
and all of this dir's have file `bar.txt`, finally not every bar.txt have `add php5` line.

How i can get output of every path's where is included `add php5`

Right now I have somehing like this:

`sudo find /home/ -name .htaccess -exec grep -r 'add php5' {} \;`

And this gives me only output like this:

`AddHandler php5-fastcgi php`

`AddHandler php5-fastcgi php`

and more more more.

How I can get PWD of this outputs?

Comment: `grep -r --include '.htaccess' 'add php5' /home`?

Comment: Ok, its nice, that was helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the file name include in the output, use '-H' on the grep. If you just want the file name, use '-l'

```
# File and lines
sudo find /home/ -name .htaccess -exec grep -H -r 'add php5' {} \;

# Only file
sudo find /home/ -name .htaccess -exec grep -l -r 'add php5' {} \;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do:

```
grep -r --include '.htaccess' 'add php5' /home
```

that way `grep` will print the filename.

You can also "trick" `grep` into thinking it's been passed multiple files:

```
find /home/ -name .htaccess -exec grep -r 'add php5' /dev/null {} \;
```

Comment: The '-H' tells grep to include the filename, even when there is only one input file, eliminating the need to "trick" grep into believing there are multiple input files.